# How to find the number of rows in a namedtuple collection?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
Action = namedtuple('Action', 'name index delta_i delta_j')
up = Action('up', 0, -1, 0)    
down = Action('down', 1, 1, 0)    
left = Action('left', 2, 0, -1)    
right = Action('right', 3, 0, 1)
```

I know there are 4 actions in the collection Action.

But what if I don't know? What Python code do I use to find out?

UPDATE

I have found out from the answers that there is no answer to this question.
Action is a class rather than a collection. I am tempted to delete this question, although it may help someone like me who is new to Python.

Comment: Store the actions in a list, if you are referring to the number of actions.  This question is a vague.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer I hope. It is the number of actions in the collection

Comment: There is no collection "`Action`" here though. `Action` is a class, and `up`, `down`, `left`, and `right` are instances of the class. Classes don't track every instance that are created from them, so you need to manually handle that.

Comment: What you actually might be after now that I think about it is an `Enum`: `from enum import Enum; class Action(Enum): UP = (0, -1, 0); . . .`. It's essentially a "collection" of a limited set of possible options. Then you can just do `list(Action)` to get all the possible options.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which object you wish to extract the length from.

1. From one of the instances:

```py
size = len(up)
```

2. From the generated class itself, you can do e.g.

```py
size = len(Action._fields)  # try print(Action._fields)
```

3. From the string used to create the class:

```
fields = 'name index delta_i delta_j'
size = len(fields.split())  # again, try print(fields.split())
```

Comment: The way the question was phrased it sounded like they expected something along the lines of `len([i for i in globals().values() if isinstance(i, Action)])` but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Axe319 - you are right. I have edited the question I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: For that you should write up your own book-keeping. The number of times a class has been initialized is not kept track of by Python natively. If all instances are still alive, you can hack something together with e.g. `globals()` as @Axe319 write, but it won't be pretty nor robust.

Comment: Thank you for that. I was wondering why I could not find an obvious way of doing it.